# How can I remove duplicate and count values for list in RDD?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

```py
[('key1', ['word1', 'word1', 'word2', ...]),
 ('key2', ['word1', 'word2', 'word2', ...]),
 ...
]
```

I want to remove duplicate in the list and assign them to the key.

First step output: removing duplicate in list

```py
[('key1', ['word1', 'word2', ...]),
 ('key2', ['word1', 'word2', ...]),
 ...
]
```

second step output

```py
[('key1', ('word1', '1'))
 ('key1', ('word2', '1')),
 ...
 ('key2', ('word1', '1')),
 ('key2', ('word2', '1')),
 ...
]
```

Here's my try which does not work.

```py
rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], (x[1], 1])).collect()
```

Output:

```py
[('key1', (['word1', 'word1', 'word2', ...], 1)),
 ('key2', (['word1', 'word2', 'word2', ...], 1)),
 ...
]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As someone already indicated in the comments above, you cannot count the entries after you removed duplicates.  Ideally, this should happen during the same operation.

Your question is not entirely clear.  Hence, I am assuming that you want to transform the RDD

```
[('key1', ['word1', 'word2', 'word2']),
 ('key2', ['word1', 'word2', 'word2']),
 ('key3', ['word1', 'word2', 'word2']),
]
```

to

```
[('key1', {'word1': 1, 'word2': 2}), 
 ('key2', {'word1': 1, 'word2': 2}), 
 ('key3', {'word1': 1, 'word2': 2})
]
```

You could achieve this with the following code snippet:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = (SparkSession
        .Builder()
        .getOrCreate()
        )
sc = spark.sparkContext
from typing import List

mylist = [('key1', ['word1', 'word2', 'word2']),
          ('key2', ['word1', 'word2', 'word2']),
          ('key3', ['word1', 'word2', 'word2']),
         ]
myrdd = sc.parallelize(mylist)
rdd2 = myrdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], wordcounter(x[1])))
```

where the function `wordcounter` could be something like

```
def wordcounter(words: List[str]) -> dict:
    """
    Count every unique entry in the list
    """
    out = {}
    for ii in words:
        if ii in out:
            out[ii] = out[ii] + 1
        else:
            out[ii] = 1
    return out
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a combination of `map` and `flatMap` with `collections.Counter()`. the `Counter` will output the frequency of the elements in a list as a dict.

here's the example

```py
from collections import Counter

data_ls = [
    ('key1', ['word1', 'word1', 'word2']),
    ('key2', ['word1', 'word2', 'word2'])
]

spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls). \
    map(lambda r: (r[0], Counter(r[1]).items())). \
    flatMap(lambda r: [(r[0], k) for k in r[1]]). \
    collect()

# [('key1', ('word1', 2)),
#  ('key1', ('word2', 1)),
#  ('key2', ('word1', 1)),
#  ('key2', ('word2', 2))]
```